# Initializing State property on heap versus on initState function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

coming from Kotlin(Android) I wanted to know which of the below code is the recommended way to initialize a simple boolean state property in flutter

```
...
class _LogInPagePageState extends State<LogInPage> {
  bool obscurePasswords = true;  //Is it better to set the initial value of obscurePasswords here?

  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    obscurePasswords = true; //Or is it more preferred here?
  }
....
```

Which is the best place to create the initial state of something as simple as the `obscurePassword` property